# Any chance to display focus loss on maximized window in KDE?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, kde, kde-plasma-5

I am using KDE on multiple monitors. This makes it possible to have several maximized windows (on different monitors). Unfortunately, KDE designers thought tha maximized window can be only one and decided not to display focus loss on maximized window. If I have 3 monitors and each has maximized window on it, it is hard to see, which one is active, and which one is not.

Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I‘m not sure what you mean by “display focus loss”, but there is a “Dim Inactive” desktop effect you can enable in System Settings. Another way which I use is to have a widget (for example “Active Window Control”) showing the active window’s icon and name so you know which one is being focused.